# Compile protobuf for python on Win7 issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I started to learn Tensorflow from a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWFg6R5ccOc) and this is the first time I deal with Google's Protobuf. I'am stuck at protobuf compilation step.

I've downloaded Tensorflow [models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) and [protoc-3.4.0-win32](https://github.com/google/protobuf)

Now I have to run compilation command from a terminal however an error occurs:

1) `cd C:\TensorFlow\models\research`

2) `“C:\protoc-3.4.0-win32\bin\protoc.exe” object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

As a result I have an error:

`"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"`

I have no idea why this error occurs and how to fix it. May be I missed something or I should set some special enviroment configs, i.d.k.

I use Win7 x64, Python 3.6.6

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/3957) help?

Comment: @shahkalpesh, thanks! That helped me. Just copied `protoc.exe` from `C:\protoc-3.4.0-win32\bin` to the `C:\TensorFlow\models\research` directory and run `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.` command, that worked out.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `protoc` version 3 but the proto files in object detection are using `syntax = "proto2";` So you need to use `protoc` [version 2](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v2.6.1).